# ggplot: position legend in top left

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot made with ggplot2 and I'd like to get the legend positioned in the **top left corner**.

`legend.position = "top"` gets me a legend positioned above the plot, but centered:

[image: Legend is on top, but centered]

`legend.position = c(0,1)` gets the legend in the top left, but it floats over the other plot elements:

[image: Look at that legend float!]

Know how to get that legend up in the top left without having it float? I tried declaring the legend height, but no dice. Do I have to adjust the size and position of the title and plot area?

Thanks!

Comment: You can further refine the position with `legend.justification=c(1,1)` - for example, `p + theme(legend.position=c(1,1), legend.justification=c(1,1))`.  Since this will still be plotting in the graphics area, you may also want to play around with `legend.background=element_blank()` and `legend.key=element.blank()`.

Comment: Thanks, I mistyped in the original question (it's since been edited). I meant top left, sorry! `legend.justification` is helpful in positioning the legend just right, but it floats over the graphics area. I'd like to get the legend out of the graphics area, like `legend.position = "top"` does so nicely.

Answer (score 42):

It can be done with legend.justification using predefined options.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle("No title needed") +
  theme(legend.position='top', 
        legend.justification='left',
        legend.direction='horizontal')
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

How about something like this -- not sure if there's a way to avoid the "hack" of `\n\n\n` in the call to `ggtitle()`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle("A Title for Plot\n\n\n") +
  theme(
           legend.position = c(0, 1), 
      legend.justification = c(0, 0),
          legend.direction = "horizontal"
  )
```

[image: Plot with Left-Justified Title Above Plot]

Comment: Thanks! Gosh, that's a lot simpler than my solution: use gridExtra to cut out the title, legend, and plot and then rearrange them in a table: https://gist.github.com/conorsg/54f99d46206301f74169#file-gistfile1-r

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this didn't work for my plot- i'm guessing it's because my y axis tick text is too long and the plot legend tries to align itself to the plot area, not the axis ticks. Just as Conor Gaffney i was about to embark on using gridExtra to cut out the legend until i came across this post [R ggplot2: Change the spacing between the legend and the panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362895/r-ggplot2-change-the-spacing-between-the-legend-and-the-panel)

you can simply use `legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,-100)` in `theme()` to force alignment to the left! Hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: While the information in your link may solve the OP's question, answers that rely heavily on a link are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained with a minimal amount of code so others can verify that it works. Include the data you used, and an example of your output. Thanks

Comment: And given you are linking to an existing SO answer, there is a case that this should be posted as a comment on the relevant answer rather than as a new answer.