# R ggplot2: Change the spacing between the legend and the panel

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I change the spacing between the legend area and the panel in `ggplot2 2.2.0`?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfr <- data.frame(x=factor(1:20),y1=runif(n=20)) %>%
        mutate(y2=1-y1) %>%
        gather(variable,value,-x)


ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.justification="right")
```

Changing `legend.margin` or `legend.box.margin` doesn't seem to do anything.

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.justification="right",
        legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0),
        legend.box.margin=margin(0,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Actually, I think the options you mentioned will work. They seem to work for me; perhaps you didn't input appropriate values.

Have a look at these 2 to see what I'm talking about:

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.justification="right",
        legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0),
        legend.box.margin=margin(-10,-10,-10,-10))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.justification="right",
        legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0),
        legend.box.margin=margin(10,10,10,10))
```

[image]

Comment: ah yes! It does work. Thanks. The values have changed a lot.

Comment: Isn't that strange though? A margin of 0 should already bring it very close to the graph? Does it mean there is another margin element that we are overlapping on by setting a negative margin?

Comment: @Matifou Yes it turns out there is. Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73880769/3275826

Answer (score 13):

There is a theme option `legend.box.spacing` which adjusts the space between the legend and plot area.

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
geom_bar(stat="identity")+
theme(legend.position="top",
      legend.justification="right", 
      legend.box.spacing = unit(0, "pt")) # The spacing between the plotting area and the legend box (unit)
```

Here is the original alongside the adjusted one

[image: original][image: with legend.box.spacing=0]

And by adjusting the `legend.margin` as well you can have the legend touching the panel.

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity")+
 theme(legend.position="top",
       legend.justification="right", 
       legend.box.spacing = unit(0, "pt"),# The spacing between the plotting area and the legend box (unit)
       legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0))# the margin around each legend
```

[image: with no legend.box.spacing nor legend.margin]

`legend.box.margin` doesn't have an effect (at least in theme grey) because it is defined as `legend.box.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "cm")`